# Octave value list datatype

Tags: c++, octave

I'm using Octave in cpp code. I call Octave functions using feval. The code is-

```
octave_value_list out = feval (pstData[0], in, 1);
```

Which function do I have to use to determine the data type and size of each element in the list `out`? I have to check if the element is scalar/2D matrix/hypermatrix, the data type- complex/real/int/float/double/bool/string and the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://octave.org/doxygen/4.0/d6/db6/classoctave__value__list.html#ae35d4c9baeb4f13ee1f4e5905ba8044f) of `octave_value_list`, I'd say you can access its elements through the `operator()`. This way, you will get an `octave_value`, a type that offers [all the functions you need](http://octave.org/doxygen/4.0/d3/d35/classoctave__value.html), like `is_float_type()`, `is_double_type()`, etc..

Example (not tested)

```
octave_value& v = out(2); // access the value with id 2
bool is_double = v.is_double_type; // check wether out(2) is a double
```